# Deserialize xml elements with the same name into List

Tags: c#, xml, restsharp, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize xml file with structure like this:

```
<items>
   <item id="1">
      <group>1</group>
      <param name="Width">100</param>
      <param name="Length">100</param>
      <price>100</price>
      <name>Name 1</name>
      <param name="Weight" unit="gr">100</param>
   </item>

   <item id="2">
      <group>1</group>
      <param name="Width">200</param>
      <param name="Length">200</param>
      <price>200</price>
      <name>Name 2</name>
      <param name="Weight" unit="gr">200</param>
   </item>

   <item id="3">
      <group>3</group>
      <price>300</price>
      <name>Name 3</name>
      <param name="Weight" unit="lbs">300</param>
   </item>
</items>
```

The only problem is `param` elements. In different `item` element there can be from 1 to 3 of `param` elements. I need all of them to be deserialized, but list `Param` is always ending up empty.

My de-serialization classes looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot("items")]
public class Items
{
    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("group")]
    public int Group{ get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("price")]
    public decimal  Price { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("param")]
    public List<Param> Params { get; set; }

}


[XmlRoot("param")]
public class Param
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    
    [DeserializeAs(Content = true)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Also tried to add `[XmlArray("param")]` and `[XmlArrayItem("param")]` but result is the same.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this class. Or maybe there is another way how can I deserialize this `param` elements as individual properties?

Comment: `I'm trying to deserialize xml file with structure like this`, where's your attempt at deserializing this, it's missing.

Comment: Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer

Comment: You are missing :[XmlElement()]public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }.  Without XmlElement the serialize library is looking for two xml tags and you only have one.

Comment: Items is deserializing just fine even without `[XmlElement()]`. The problem with `public List<Param> Param`

Comment: Only the LIST needs the XmlElement.  When you do not have the XmlElement the serializer is looking for two tags Params and Param.  You only have Param.

Comment: I added XmlElement to the List 'Items' but it's all the same. List 'Param' is still empty

Comment: you can't create property and class with the same name. may be you should add `[XmlElement("item")]` to items property after rename it. is this `DeserializeAs` a custom attribute. try to use just `[XmlText]` for the ``Value`` property to get the value.

Comment: `DeserializeAs` is just a RestSharp attribute (sorry forgot to add restsharp tag to the question) and it works same as `[XmlText]`. But the problem is not with it. If I change public `public List<Param> Params` to `public Param Parameter` it will deserialize the first `param` element just fine. Problem is - I need all of them to be deserialized.

Comment: @Maxim so why this work for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/idrhpa

Comment: @MohammedSajid Yes you were right, thank you. Solution was `[XmlText]`. Didn't realize this, because everything worked okay, when there's only 1 `param` element